Is it possible to have a pattern that allows special characters but no spaces?
My pattern currently allows letters and does not allow spaces and numbers, intentionally. However, I would like to allow characters such as !@#$%^&*()_+=-[]|}{;'":,./?>< for my pattern and input type. How would I doe this?
I tried searching all over the internet and found lots of solutions but none of them worked for me.
Here is my code:
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="get">
            <input type="number" min="0" max="150" name="Age"/>
            <input type="text" name="Name" pattern="[A-Za-z]+"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>


Have you tried just adding the characters to the pattern=? What happened? It would also be helpful to [edit] your question and include what you've tried already and how that didn't solve the problem.

[^\s] matches any character that is NOT a whitespace character.
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="get">
            <input type="number" min="0" max="150" name="Age"/>
            <input type="text" pattern="^[^\s]+$">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>


Try:
[^\d\s]+

Explanation:
Any amount of characters [...]+ that is not ^ a number \d or whitespace \s.
Examples:
RegEx101


<form method="POST" action="https://httpbin.org/post" target="response">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Numbers and spaces are <b>not</b> permitted</legend>
    <input name="No_Number_or_Spaces" pattern="[^\d\s]+" style="display: inline-block; width: 87%" required value="!@#$%^&*()_+=-[]|}{;'&quot;:,./?><Aa">
    <button>Send</button>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Response from live test server</legend>
    <iframe name="response" width="100%"></iframe>
  </fieldset>
</form>



